# Can't run debug mode with babelua on vs2013

Tags: lua, babelua

I installed babelua extension on vs2013 and can run my "hello world" script by clicking "LUA>starting without debugging", but I want to be able to run and make it pause at a certain break point. So I tried clicking "Debug>start debugging" and I keep getting an error window saying "Error starting process C:\program files\lua\lua.exe". Anything I need to do on vs2013 to run the extension babelua under debug mode? [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with BabeLua. I never learned what caused it exactly, but switching from a "Lua for Windows" install to a luarocks install worked for me.